# Prove the identity ${(\csc^2x+1)^2 \over\csc^2x }+ {(\sec^2x+1)^2\over \sec^2x} = \tan^2x +\cot^2x +7$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$${(\csc^2x+1)^2 \over \csc^2x }+{ (\sec^2x+1)^2  \over\sec^2x} = \tan^2x +\cot^2x +7$$
I began working on the left side of the equation, and the first thing I did was get a common denominator, I can't figure out how to get things to start canceling out.

Comment: Start with $$\tan^2x+1=\sec^2x,\cot^2x+1=\csc^2x$$

Comment: Can you please confirm the correctness of the present version?

Comment: No the correct equation is ((csc^2x+1)^2 /csc^2x) + ((sec^2x+1)^2)/ sec^2x) = tan^2x + cot^2x +7

Comment: Please double check my edit to verify correctness

Comment: Not sure why tag 'Trigonometry' is missing

Answer (score 1):

$${(\csc^2x+1)^2 \over \csc^2x }=\left(\frac{\csc^2x+1}{\csc x}\right)^2=\left(\csc x+\sin x\right)^2\text{ as }\frac1{\csc x}=\sin x$$

So,we have 
$$(\csc x+\sin x)^2+(\sec x+\cos x)^2=\csc^2x+2+\sin^2x+\sec^2x+2+\cos^2x$$

Now use $$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1;\sec^2x=\tan^2x+1;\csc^2x=\cot^2x+1$$